# Biscom Integration with Salesforce

Tags: integration

i am looking for Biscom App for Salesforce for Automated Email/Fax sending process but i am unable to find it on Web . help me out to find the Biscom Package for Salesforce or any other heuristic Approach to integrate Biscom Fax service with Salesforce....

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist, but we created it, their solution only handled communications between SFDC and a Faxcom server. Everything inside SFDC had to be built..but the good news is, we just finished a full implementation of the Biscom/Faxcom to SFDC, complete with document generation/handling for faxing out from Accounts/Contacts/Cases as well as inbound routing using a barcode to automatically attach the returned fax to the Contact/Case Object. Be happy to discuss further if you're still interested, otherwise you'll want to reach out to Biscom for their basic connector.
[image: Inbound Fax Handler]
[![Document Generator][2]][2]
[image: Send Outbound Fax]